# Is there a proper noun for the person being proposed for a job interview?

Tags: proper-nouns

In a proposing a proposer propose a *blank* for a job. I am not sure if it exists.

Comment: Proper noun or a general term? Do you mean, 'endorsed'? 'referral'?

Comment: A person who definitely IS to be interviewed could be called an ***interviewee***, but that's not a particularly common usage. Usually we'd use the same word we use for someone who has been *proposed, suggested, nominated* for interview - a ***candidate*** (or ***applicant***, but that one more strongly implies the person proposed *themselves* for the job, rather than being put forward by others).

Comment: You can nominate somebody for a job, and the person is a **nominee**.

Answer (score 5):

Candidate or applicant maybe appropriately used for a person being interviewed for a job (in addition to the above).

Comment: The person interviewing for a job is *the interviewer*.  Although *candidate* could be used for *interviewee* who is being interviewed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a noun for someone who will be interviewed for a job, I suggest 'interviewee'.

A proper noun is a name, like Mary Smith, London, or Hoover Dam. Proper nouns are usually capitalized. A proper noun for an interviewee would be their actual name.